# PHP Setting HTTP Cookie

Tags: php, cookies, http-headers

I want to add a cookie using PHP to the browser which the expiration date is one year after the cookie is set. I have set the variable name,value,path "/",domain and the expiry date. However, when I close the browser and open the website again using the same browser, no cookies are sent to the web page. What happened? The cookie is still applicable if I only close the window only. Yet things happened when the application is shut down and opened again.

```
setcookie("LANG","english",time()+365*60*60*24,"/","sub.domain.org");
```

Comment: Show the code you use to set the cookie.

Comment: Is the cookie still in the browser when you re-open the browser? Firefox for example lets you show all cookies.

Comment: Are you not using some clean-on-exit plugin, or perhaps incognito mode?

Comment: No! I am not using any of the modes.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am not using Firefox and I will check if there are cookie.

Comment: Are you trying to set the cookie after you have already made output to the browser?

Comment: I am not sure what you are talking about, Mike. What I want to do is only to store the language of the user so that when next time he or she browse the website using the same browser again, the cookie could be retrieved.

Comment: One new report. This problem only exist in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to set the cookie:

```
$expire=time()+60*60*24*365;
    setcookie("name", value, $expire);
```

to bring to cookie again:

```
$_COOKIE['name']
```

Comment: I have done everything. What I mean is the BROWSER does not sent any cookie to the web page even though I set the cookie.

Comment: If you use $_COOKIE it will send the cookie, otherwise it won't

Comment: My purpose is to store the cookie in the system so that it can be used  each time when I visit the website again.

Comment: What do you mean? You mean if I do not retrieve the cookie, then the browser will not send the cookie??

Comment: if you have the name and value right it will use it, but it is very probable that they encrypted the cookie

Comment: If so, how can I store the cookie in the browser history?

Comment: If the browser has a cookie that is eligible to be sent, it will send it, even if you never use it. It is part of the request header. Check in the browser's list of cookies if the cookie is still there when you restart. If not, your browser delete the cookie and there is nothing you as webdeveloper can do about it.

Comment: How can I send a cookie that is eligible to be sent?

Comment: I found one interesting thing. Firefox works in my PC yet Google Chrome is not.